# Can I dynamically add content to a frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, iframe, frame

I have a frame and I want to dynamically add content to it with javascript or jquery but I can't do something like $('#myframe').html() like I could for a DIV. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to in the first place? Why not just use a `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/fb646741a6192540) discusses various solutions for dynamically adding content to a frame.